# Fastreport - barcode1 color bar property does not exist

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, fastreport

After create two identical applications one work fine other has below error. Also some other old app work some get error. Any solution where is problem, I use Fast report 6?

**barcode1 colorBar property does not exist!**

[image]

Comment: What happens when you open the form in the IDE?

Comment: `ColorBar` property did not exists in FR 5, so the projects throwing this error are compiled  with version earlier than 6.

Comment: @BrakNicku  This error occur after install Rad Studio 10.4  and FastReport 6.9.3.  This error I get on Rad studio 10.3  and FastReport 6.3.3. Maybe there is some conflict.

Comment: @fpiette Build app is ok, but when try open .exe get error. When open form all looks good without error.

Comment: When displaying a debugger exception, don't post images of the dialog. Instead, while the dialog is open hit Ctrl+C, which puts a text copy of the dialog on the clipboard, which can then be pasted into your question here. That means no need to do screen captures and no need to upload images at all, which is better for people with visibility issues or using mobile devices, or that are behind a corporate proxy that prevents the images from being seen at all.

Comment: @babayaro as you can find [here](https://www.fast-report.com/en/news/446/) `ColorBar` has been in fact introduced in 6.6, so that explains why you are getting these errors in 6.3.3.